# Can material sent to me as the proposed content of a website fall foul of GDPR regulation?

Tags: legal, gdpr

I have a friend who insists that material sent to me by a client as part of the proposed content of a website they are contracting me to build can qualify as sensitive data and as such can fall foul of the EU's new GDPR regulation.

So taking the following example: I have a customer who contracts me to build them a website. They provide me with the content that they want on the pages (a publicly-accessible website that anyone with an internet connection can see). If that content contains personal info (e.g. names, photos, employment history) then I, as the web-developer, am now in possession of "sensitive information" and need to abide by all the relevant legislation for handling this information; despite the fact that they have given me this of their own volition with the express purpose of displaying it publicly on their website.

To be clear, according to what I am being told, if I was being tasked with building a web page with staff info like [this one](http://oakworthconsultancy.co.uk/people) for example, then having the client send me the staff names and photos means that I am now "processing personal data".

This seems ridiculous to me, and not what the regulation was intended for; namely the *soliciting* and *harvesting* of personal information for targeted-marketing purposes, which is obviously not at all what is happening here. Surely if I am simply sent a mass of material and asked to put it on a website then by doing so I am merely fulfilling a contract?

What are your thoughts on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like contractors do fall under GDPR; but in certain situations do not have to register.

> [The EU General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) is aimed at all organisations or individuals who hold or use personal data for business or other organisational activities, regardless of their size or structure.](https://www.contractoruk.com/successful_contracting/contractors_questions_does_gdpr_require_contractors_register.html)
>
> [General GDPR requirements include using personal data fairly; identifying the purposes for which you hold it, letting individuals know what you do with their data, not holding more data than you need, deleting it when you no longer need it, and keeping data up-to-date and secure.](https://www.contractoruk.com/successful_contracting/contractors_questions_does_gdpr_require_contractors_register.html)
>
> [In relation to registration, the GDPR itself does not require a general data protection registration for any business or organisation (although does require consultation with authorities in some situations). However, in the UK, there will be a requirement for some organisations to pay annual data protection charges, and provide basic information, in accordance with the Data Protection (Charges and Information) Regulations 2018.](https://www.contractoruk.com/successful_contracting/contractors_questions_does_gdpr_require_contractors_register.html)

In fact, your client has GDPR responsibilities with regards to contractors.

> [Controllers must supervise how outside contractors process data along with internal data processors.](https://www.secureworks.com/blog/2018-gdpr-compliance-overview)
>
> [The controller is also responsible for making sure that outside contractors comply.](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3202771/data-protection/general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr-requirements-deadlines-and-facts.html)